# How library packaging works in android

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have confusion that how the android packaging works with library, Say i am used some kotlin experimental apis in my application.I have published the application, Say After the production the experimental api which i have used have major change.

> Does my app which is already published get affected?

Can anyone resolve my confusion?

Comment: All libraries are packaged into your apk and installed alongside your app and any changes made to those libraries have no effect on existing publications/installations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Packaging are the group of libraries that you used for your particular task.
Suppose you want to use retrofit Networking library in your project, However, you need to use some callback method and those callback methods will import via package.

Here one more practical example, you want to work with Java then JAVA SDK here, you have to set in environment variable then you use methods in your framework.

Now let me come of Effection, so yes some libraries got update and some deprecate due to advancement feature. Yes, it impacts on your project. not in meantime but yes in future if there is any advance feature.

Comment: will the impact will be on the published app or in my project?

Comment: At the meantime will not crash or provide any exception.  will run smooth after published. they will provide warning in future in source code if there is any update.